# SQLException: Communications link failure (Java/mysql)

Tags: java, mysql

Can someone explain to me why this line works:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://myWebsite.com:3306/schemaName?user=userX&password=passwordX");
```

But this line does not:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schemaName?user=userX&password=passwordX");
```

I get a Communications Link Failure when attempting to access through the localhost (or 127.0.0.1). However, I'm able to access the database via localhost through PHP and the MySQLQuery Browser and MySQL Aministrator.

If needed here's the entire method I'm using:

```
public Database() throws Exception {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

try {
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://myWebsite.com:3306/schemaName?user=userX&password=passwordX");
  // Next line does not work.
  //    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schemaName?user=userX&password=passwordX");
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
      displaySQLException(ex); // Seperate routine to display errors.
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help,
Richard

Comment: does "userX" has the permission to access the database from the localhost? May be PHPandMySQl query browser and MySQL administrator uses a different user who can access to the database from the localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible your mysqld is [binding](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) specifically to the ethernet interface instead of all interfaces (0.0.0.0) or the localhost interface (127.0.0.1).

On a *nix platform you can check which interface the daemon is listening on with the following command:

```
$ netstat -ln|grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with java and/or mysql... so I don't understand why this worked, when I had no problems with other apps.
Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: @RichardRhyan The other applications may have been using a [socket](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking) interface instead of tcp.

Answer (score 0):

In second code:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schemaName?
                user=userX&password=passwordX");
```

It will try to connect to mysql on machine on localhost (*on which the code is running*). In your case it might be possible that mysql on your machine or from where you are running the code is not available or stopped or usename/password you are passing are not valid or schemaname does not exist. But on myWebsite.com it is up.

There is nothing wrong in your code. Make sure mySql is installed and running and username/password are valid, a schema with provided schemaname exists on machine on which you run this code with `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen for many reasons, like

1. MySQL server might be stopped on the target machine
2. MySQL might be configured not to accept remote connections
3. The firewall might be blocking remote connections on port 3306

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I faced this error when trying to connect to mysql-server running inside a container on a Ubuntu host VM from the same host.

Example: 
If my VM name is `abc.company.com`,  the following jdbc URL **would not work**:

`jdbc:mysql://abc.company.com:3306/dbname`

Above jdbc url would work fine from other machines like `xyz.company.com` but just not `abc.company.com`.

where as the following jdbc URL **would work just fine** on `abc.company.com` machine:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname`

which led me to check the `/etc/hosts` file.

Adding the following line to `/etc/hosts` fixed this issue:

`127.0.1.1    abc.company.com    abc`

This seems to be an OS bug that requires us to add these on some Ubuntu versions. 
Reference: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution

Before trying this, I had tried all other solutions like `GRANT ALL..`, changing the `bind-address` line in mysql.cnf.. None of them helped me in this case.